# One-loop potential correction in QED (Lamb shift)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, self-energy, lamb-shift

Vacuum polarization 1-loop in QED gives another term in potential, named Lamb shift. Potential in terms of momentum $p^2$ is:
$$V(p^2)= \frac{e^4_R}{2\pi^2p^2} \int_0^1 x(1-x)\ln[1-\frac{p^2}{m^2}x(1-x)]dx.\tag{16.56}$$

My question is how to Fourier transform potential into space to get:
$$V(r)=-\frac{e^4_R}{24\pi^3r}\int_1^\infty e^{-2mrx}\frac{2x^2+1}{2x^4}\sqrt{x^2-1} dx.\tag{16.60}$$

This is Problem 16.2 Schwartz Quantum Field Theory

Comment: The calculation is carried out in detail in Ch. 5.2 of *Quantum Electrodynamics* by Greiner & Reinhardt. Also, note that this specific form of the potential is valid for static point charges only: $j_\mu (x)=-Ze_{\text{R}}\delta(\vec{x})\delta_{\mu 0}$, hence $j_\mu(p)=-2\pi Ze_{\text{R}}\delta(p_0)\delta_\mu$. Therefore, you should replace $p^2$ by $-\vec{p}^2$ in your equations.